# O(N) Simple Diffing Algorithm Implementation -- is this right?

Tags: node.js, algorithm, time-complexity, diff

I just posted this on HN but it doesn't seem to be getting much uptake, I had a question about diffing -- I wanted to know if an implementation I'm using is alright: it seems a little too simple, and the literature on diffing is dense.

Background: I've been building a rendering engine for a code editor the past couple of days. Rendering huge chunks of highlighted syntax can get laggy. It's not worth switching to React at this stage, so I wanted to just write a quick diff algorithm that would selectively update only changed lines.

I found this article:
https://blog.jcoglan.com/2017/02/12/the-myers-diff-algorithm-part-1/

With a link to this paper, the initial Git diff implementation:
http://www.xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf

I couldn't find the PDF to start with, but read "edit graph" and immediately thought — why don't I just use a hashtable to store lines from LEFT_TEXT and references to where they are, then iterate over RIGHT_TEXT and return matches one by one, also making sure that I keep track of the last match to prevent jumbling?

The algorithm I produced is only a few lines and seems accurate. It's O(N) time complexity, whereas the paper above gives a best case of O(ND) where D is minimum edit distance.

```
  function lineDiff (left, right) {
    left = left.split('\n');
    right = right.split('\n');
    let lookup = {};
    // Store line numbers from LEFT in a lookup table
    left.forEach(function (line, i) {
      lookup[line] = lookup[line] || [];
      lookup[line].push(i);
    });
    // Last line we matched
    var minLine = -1;
    return right.map(function (line) {
      lookup[line] = lookup[line] || [];
      var lineNumber = -1;
      if (lookup[line].length) {
        lineNumber = lookup[line].shift();
        // Make sure we're looking ahead
        if (lineNumber > minLine) {
          minLine = lineNumber;
        } else {
          lineNumber = -1
        }
      }
      return {
        value: line,
        from: lineNumber
      };
    });
  }
```

RunKit link: https://runkit.com/keithwhor/line-diff

What am I missing? I can't find other references to doing diffing like this. Everything just links back to that one paper.

Comment: Heckel's (1978) "A technique for isolating differences between files" uses a hash table on lines. It does more work to form copies and moves 
of contiguous sets of lines than this. And handles matching modified lines which might not be needed here. See https://gist.github.com/ndarville/3166060 for an illustrated implementation in Python.

Comment: `lineDiff('a\nb\nc\n','c\na\nb\n')`